# Using sed to ID a pattern in rows, not columns

Tags: sed, awk, gnu, gawk, data-management

Can GNU sed be used to ID a pattern based on rows? Or in other words, how can you insert a line break in the pattern you're using sed to ID?

For example, in the following dataset (which is much larger in actuality), I have an error that should have been removed when I searched for duplicates, but was not because the information is slightly different in two rows (which is irrelevant at this point).

In this case, I want to remove the error entirely from the original file.In other words, if, within my file, two rows of `rs####` follow each other, I would like to erase these two copies, and also the six lines that follow them. It would be nice to relocate them to a new file, but what is most critical is that they are removed from the original.

```
rs1038864   16  73762557    A   G
1   1633    0.5835  -0.0004 0.0035
1   1643    0.8902  0.004436    0.004354
0   0   0   0   0
rs1019567   16  83343715    G   T
rs1019567   16  83343715    G   T
1   1641    0.4692  0.0009  0.0035
1   559 0.4612  -0.0025 0.0060
1   1643    0.5178  -0.002244   0.002745
1   1643    0.5178  -0.002244   0.002745
1   1909    0.493842692 0.0008  0.0027
1   1950    0.493842692 0.0008  0.0027
rs1038556   16  55132072    C   T
1   6388    0.7773  0.0020  0.0044
1   6843    0.1161  0.001379    0.004275
1   1509    0.978660942 0.0041  0.0096
rs1019797   16  87788686    C   G
rs1019797   16  87788686    C   G
1   1639    0.717   0.0022  0.0038
1   5557    0.7193  0.0020  0.0064
1   1643    0.6691  -0.001044   0.002888
1   6843    0.6691  -0.001044   0.002888
1   1959    0.315280799 -0.0041 0.0032
1   1909    0.315280799 -0.0041 0.0032
rs1038887   16  62660698    A   G
1   1688    0.4947  -0.0028 0.0035
0   0   0   0   0
1   1909    0.464393658 0.0007  0.0028
```

Something like,

```
sed -i '/^rs.*d
^rs.*/,+6d' test.data
```

or perhaps

```
sed -i '/^rs.*;^rs.*/,+6d' test.data
```

?
Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `infile` contains the listed input, something like this should do (GNU sed):

```
<infile sed -r 'N; /([^\n]+)\n\1/ { N; N; N; N; N; N; d }; P; D'
```

If you want to save the deleted bits to `deleted.txt` use this:

```
<infile sed -r 'N; /([^\n]+)\n\1/ { N; N; N; N; N; N; w deleted.txt
d }; P; D'
```

Note that the `w` command needs to be terminated by a newline.

*Explanation*

This loads a second line into the pattern space (`N`) and checks if the lines are duplicates (`/([^\n]+)\n\1/`), if the are six more lines are loaded into pattern space and deleted (`d`).

Comment: Why the I/O redirection at the start of the line instead of as an argument to `sed`?  It works, but it is aconventional.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Believe it or not, I find it more readable, it means I don't have search for the end of the command before discovering what input is being affected. Maybe others don't think so?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a way to modify this if the number of lines isn't always 6 following the duplicated `rs` rows? For example, if it was 5 (or 2, etc.) additional rows, how could I specify: delete the the duplicated rows, and the 5 following, until an unduplicated `rs` row?

Comment: @mfk534: You change the number of N's to specify number of extra lines to be deleted. If that number is variable you could do it by detecting non-duplicated rs lines at the end of pattern space, but that is more complicated. A better approach would be to use awk or perl as _JonathanLeffler_ suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `sed` is the right tool for the job (but I may be wrong; it depends in part on whether there are always exactly 6 lines to delete and maybe on whether the adjacent ID lines always have the same ID).  You probably can do it with `awk`, but I'd reach for Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $rejects = "reject.lines";
open my $fh, '>', $rejects or die "Failed to create $rejects";

my $old = "";

while (<>)
{
    if ($_ =~ /^rs\d+ /)
    {
        if ($old =~ /^rs\d+ /)
        {
            print $fh $old;
            print $fh $_;
            while (<>)
            {
                last if /^rs\d+ /;
                print $fh $_;
            }
            $old = $_;
            next;
        }
    }
    print $old;
    $old = $_;
}
print $old if $old ne "";
close $fh;
```

This will handle arbitrary numbers of lines after the adjacent marker lines, and doesn't depend on the two markers being identical.

#### Output

```
rs1038864   16  73762557    A   G
1   1633    0.5835  -0.0004 0.0035
1   1643    0.8902  0.004436    0.004354
0   0   0   0   0
rs1038556   16  55132072    C   T
1   6388    0.7773  0.0020  0.0044
1   6843    0.1161  0.001379    0.004275
1   1509    0.978660942 0.0041  0.0096
rs1038887   16  62660698    A   G
1   1688    0.4947  -0.0028 0.0035
0   0   0   0   0
1   1909    0.464393658 0.0007  0.0028
```

#### Reject lines

```
rs1019567   16  83343715    G   T
rs1019567   16  83343715    G   T
1   1641    0.4692  0.0009  0.0035
1   559 0.4612  -0.0025 0.0060
1   1643    0.5178  -0.002244   0.002745
1   1643    0.5178  -0.002244   0.002745
1   1909    0.493842692 0.0008  0.0027
1   1950    0.493842692 0.0008  0.0027
rs1019797   16  87788686    C   G
rs1019797   16  87788686    C   G
1   1639    0.717   0.0022  0.0038
1   5557    0.7193  0.0020  0.0064
1   1643    0.6691  -0.001044   0.002888
1   6843    0.6691  -0.001044   0.002888
1   1959    0.315280799 -0.0041 0.0032
1   1909    0.315280799 -0.0041 0.0032
```

Comment: I need to become more familiar with perl, thanks for providing this!

Comment: This is where I out myself as a true perl novice... but where in this script do I specify where the original data file should be read from?  Or how do I do so, otherwise? I've been fumbling with it, just using `perl Script.pl` to run, but it's taking quite a long time and I'm not sure if that's because it's not locating the correct file (because I haven't properly specified it), or because the file is so large.

Comment: The `while (<>)` parts read from the files named on the command line, or standard input if no files are named.  Thus I was using `perl dl.pl data` but I could have used `perl dl.pl <data` too.  Or I could have typed `perl dl.pl` and then typed the data at it.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I'm trying to apply this method but having a bit of trouble. I've left the script just as it is (maybe a mistake?), and am using `perl script.pl < test.data` to run, but my outputs include only a blank `rejects.line` file. Can you give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong? I've tried a few other (very basic) `perl` scripts to make sure it's not a problem with my path to perl. I've also tried changing the script to include: `which (<path/to/test.data>)`, but that produces the same thing. Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong for you. I tried both 5.16.2 (current, my normal version of Perl) and 5.10.0 (the oldest version I have installed), and they both seemed to work.  Are you using a more archaic version of Perl, perchance? I'm not aware of anything to prevent the script working with 5.6 or 5.8, but I've not validated that. I removed the debug lines from the script on SO, but I've just rechecked by copy'n'paste from the answer looking for differences between the two scripts and at the results; no difference. Drop me an email (see my profile) and I'll send you the debugging script.

Comment: Blanks vs tabs!  Does your test data have blank or tab separated fields?  I assumed a blank at the end; I probably shouldn't have done so.  Change the regex from `/^rs\d+ /` to `/^rs\d+\s/` (three times) and you should be OK.